# ios - reloadData TableView & Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I am having a bit of trouble with reloading my tableView which is set in a UIViewController.

- It is populated with CoreData (This works)
- It is also got a custom TableViewCell for some design purposes

Now normally what I would use is this : `[_mainTableView reloadData];`

That does not work this time.

Is this because of the custom Cell or is Core Data's FetchRequest which loads fine initially and shows the data when I relaunch the app??

I have seen several questions and tutorials on SO and Google, but none of them seem to work in my case.

I have also explored these methods:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

found here: [beignUpdates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678450/892628)

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: So you have verified that the updated data is coming from Core Data, and but it is not getting to the tableview, correct?

Comment: Yes Correct:-) I have checked in the app by restarting it and also in Firefox with SQLite plugin

Comment: Where are you calling reloadData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the input, I finally got it sorted.

Instead of calling the `[_mainTableView reloadData]` I had to call the fetchmethod again.

```
    if (_managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    _managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"After _managedObjectContext: %@", _managedObjectContext);
}

[self setupFetchedResultsController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized your table view? Please try this:

[self.mainTableView reloadData];

Hope, it'll work. And, since you reload it at viewWillAppear, please sure that neither it allocate new times nor it's delegate/datasource assign again, if it is then, first time, do something like that:

_mainTableView.delegate = nil;
_mainTableView.delegate = self;//similarly, for datasource...

And, you need to explicitly call your viewWillAppear(I suppose you're already doing this.)

Please let me know in any concern.

Thanks.